# Can't pass data into the view, using a Data Mapper / Gateway design pattern. :(

Tags: php, zend-framework

I can't get the data displayed on my view. And I'm not getting why.

I have a **gateway** defined like this:

```
//application/models/Dbtable/Contact.php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Contact extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name = 'Contact';
}
```

I have a **Mapper** like this:

```
//application/models/mappers/Contact.php

class Application_Model_Mapper_Contact
{

    protected $_dbTable;

    public function setDbTable($dbTable) 
    {
        if (is_string($dbTable)) 
        {
            $dbTable = new $dbTable();
        }

        if (!$dbTable instanceof Zend_Db_Table_Abstract) 
        {
            throw new Exception('Invalid table data gateway provided');
        }

        $this->_dbTable = $dbTable;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDbTable() 
    {
        if (null === $this->_dbTable) 
        {
            $this->setDbTable('Application_Model_DbTable_Contact');
        }

        return $this->_dbTable;
    }


    public function fetchAll() 
    {
        $resultSet = $this->getDbTable()->fetchAll();

        $entries = array();

        foreach ($resultSet as $row) 
        {

            $entry = new Application_Model_Contact();

            $entry->setId($row->id);
            $entry->setname($row->name);
            $entry->setaddress($row->address);

            $entries[] = $entry;        

        }

        return $entries;
    }
}
```

Then, I have a **Domain Object** like this:

```
//application/models/Contact.php

class Application_Model_Contact
{
    protected $_id;
    protected $_name;
    protected $_address;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    public function getname() {
        return $this->_name;
    }

    public function setname($name) {
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    public function getaddress() {
        return $this->_address;
    }

    public function setaddress($address) {
        $this->_address = $address;
    }


}
```

Then, I have a **controller** like this:

```
//application/controllers/ContactController.php

class ContactController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {

    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $Contact = new Application_Model_Mapper_Contact();        
        $this->view->entries = $Contact->fetchAll();
    }


}
```

Finally I get a **view** like this:

```
//application/views/Contact/index.phml

<dl>
   <?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry): ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->escape($entry->name) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->address) ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</dl>
```

I'm getting:

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   Application_Model_Contact::$name

And it's right, because, if I dump `$this->entries` I get no property with this name.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(Application_Model_Contact)#50 (3) {
    ["_id":protected]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["_name":protected]=>
    string(5) "NameA"
    ["_address":protected]=>
    string(7) "AddressA"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Application_Model_Contact)#52 (3) {
    ["_id":protected]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["_name":protected]=>
    string(5) "NameB"
    ["_address":protected]=>
    string(7) "AddressB"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Application_Model_Contact)#54 (3) {
    ["_id":protected]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["_name":protected]=>
    string(5) "NameC"
    ["_address":protected]=>
    string(7) "AddressC"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Application_Model_Contact)#56 (3) {
    ["_id":protected]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["_name":protected]=>
    string(5) "NameD"
    ["_address":protected]=>
    string(7) "AddressD"
  }
}
```

If of course, I do:

```
<dl>
   <?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry): ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->escape($entry->_name) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->_address) ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</dl>
```

I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot access protected
>   property
>   Application_Model_Contact::$_name

And it makes sense, because, it is protected.

I've tried to follow *Zend Quick Guide Tutorial* structure, but I can't figure this out.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

**How can we properly display those elements on the view ? What am I missing ?**

**Update:**
As OZ_ pointed out, I indeed could use the getters, but what is bugging me is that, on Zend Quick Start Tutorial, where I've based my structure, they DON'T use getters on the view, so perhaps, I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks a lot for your time here.

Comment: then read tutorial without exceptions :) I don't see __get() and __set() in your model, despite that it described in tutorial. But, I recommend you to use getters and setters, because it's more 'truly' OOP way (object can be described in Interface). __get() and __set() it's 'magic', handy in short way, but more dirty.

Comment: Indeed I've not used those because I don't really understand them. So, because they use magic getters and setters, they can set and get, without calling getName, and getAddress? Because, it's the only difference I see there. Well, I will NOT use the comfort of magic methods without understand them. I have read the php manual about them, they are still not clear to me. I believe magical also means "lack of clarification on the explanation", so it must not be only me... :))) Anyway, briefly, you are saying: use the way you are using, you are doing fine, and that's the way it' supposed to work?

Comment: Direct and clean using is always better, than magic. So yes, use getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you OZ_ for your time here, really, sometimes we get stuck for hours, and I was stuck for hours last night trying to understand why was this this way. I recall to copy magic methods as well, but for some reason, that didn't work either. Anyway, the hard part, is when we have a question that, for solving it, we have to show a lot of lines. So, again, thanks for your time here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getters to get property:
`$this->escape($entry->_name)`
replace with
`$this->escape($entry->getname())`
and other properties in same way.
Protected and private fields can be accessed only through the getters and setters.

This can be useful to read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: please take a look onto my update, is just to make sure I'm making everything right. :s